# How to use mail archives in Wanderlust

Tags: wanderlust

A couple of questions related to mail archives: (1) what should the "elmo archive" that the manual refers to look like internally? Have not been able to find anything about this in google. (2) I have zip files containing what seems to be Maildirs, and have lines like this in `.folders`:

```
$name;zip;topdirectory
```

But when I open Wanderlust, it says this does not exist and should it be created. Have not experimented further, as I am clearly not able to express what I mean in the config file. Can Wanderlust handle Maildir inside zip? Also, (3) does anybody know a practical way to convert Outlook `.pst` files into something Wanderlust can understand? Have tried some tools (`readpst`, `mb2md` I think) but got lots of garbage (empty directories with strange names etc) and could not get Wanderlust to open any of the files.

Is "mbox" and Wanderlust "news spool" the same thing?

Comment: If you cannot find anything to figure out how to get `.pst` to a Wanderlust compatible format, consider figuring out how to import those things into a working mail server (either on your computer, or in cyberspace) and then use `offlineimap` or similar tool to create local `Maildir` folder.  I realize that is lo-tech and not a programmer's way of thinking about things, but I'm not a real programmer, so that's all I have to offer on this issue ...  As to archives, if you don't get an answer here in a few days, launch an issue on Github for the Wanderlust package and the gurus that maintain it..

Comment: Yes, thanks. I thought it would be possible to just import and then export with Thunderbird, but it was not (cannot remember why).

Comment: Only one question per question, please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the archive functionality of Wanderlust.

Reading through the source code, it is clear that Wanderlust is designed for working with IMAP servers and with mailbox formats that store one e-mail per file (such as MH or Maildir).  It looks like the archive support was more or less happily retrofitted to the design, and is likely to be fragile and inefficient.

Do yourself a favour — archive your mail in a robust format that Wanderlust supports well, such as MH or Maildir.